# SharpGS how to download file?

Tags: download, cloud, storage, google-cloud-storage

I am using SharpGS for google cloud storage. I could upload file using the 
`GetBucket("some-bucket").AddObject()` method but I could not download the file using the following code

```
GetBucket("some-bucket").GetObjectHead("some-file").Content
```

It gave me null value for the byte return

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `GetObjectHead` looks up the object using a `HEAD` request, so it doesn't retrieve the content.

If you take a look at the [demo code](https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs/blob/master/SharpGsDemo/Program.cs#L40), you can retrieve object contents by listing the bucket:

```
var bucket = GetBucket("some-bucket");
foreach (var o in bucket.Objects) {
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(o.Retrieve().Content));
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to get an `IObject` without listing the bucket. I would suggest adding a method to the `IObjectContent` class returned from `GetObjectHead` to fetch the `IObject`. The project is on GitHub.